# Parenting Mesh to Armature Deforms Mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

When using the parent function to parent my mesh to my armature it deforms my mesh and creates a giant copy of the mesh that spreads across the project. I am using the Armature Deform with Automatic Weights function. I am not sure what could be causing the issues since I believed it to be Auto-Run Python Scripts was disabled but that is not the case.

[image]

Comment: Here is a picture after adding the armature.  http://imgur.com/a/4n6Yy

Comment: Hi, difficult to say from here, maybe try to upload the test file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link...

Comment: I found out the issue. Turns out there was an armature already attached to the mesh that was causing some unwanted results when I tried to attach new armature. Everything appears to be working now.